# WiX: Setting values as a Composite of Multiple Properties

Tags: windows, installation, wix

Is it possible, and if so how can I create a single value from multiple properties within a WiX installation project?

Specifically, I have some dialog like this...

```
<Dialog Id="ConnectionStringDlg" Width="370"
         Height="270" Title="Database Settings - [ProductName]" NoMinimize="yes">
    <!-- Connection String -->
    <Control Id="TitleLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="60" Width="100" Height="15" TabSkip="yes" Text="Connection String" />
    <Control Id="DSLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="77"
      Width="100" Height="15" TabSkip="no" Text="&amp;Data Source: " />
    <Control Id="DSEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="92"
      Width="220" Height="18" Property="CONNECTION_STRING_DS" Text="{200}" />
    <Control Id="ICLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="107"
      Width="100" Height="15" TabSkip="no" Text="&amp;Initial Catalog: " />
    <Control Id="ICEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="122"
      Width="220" Height="18" Property="CONNECTION_STRING_IC" Text="{200}" />
    <Control Id="UIDLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="137"
      Width="100" Height="15" TabSkip="no" Text="&amp;User ID: " />
    <Control Id="UIDEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="152"
      Width="220" Height="18" Property="CONNECTION_STRING_UI" Text="{200}" />
    <Control Id="PassLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="167"
      Width="100" Height="15" TabSkip="no" Text="&amp;Password: " />
    <Control Id="PassEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="182" Password="yes"
      Width="220" Height="18" Property="CONNECTION_STRING_PASS" Text="{200}" />
    <!-- Back button -->
    <!--<Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243"
             Width="56" Height="17" Text="&amp;Back">
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="PoolSettingsDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>-->
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243"
           Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="&amp;Next">
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">
        <!--if settings are correct, allow next dialog-->
        <![CDATA[CONNECTION_STRING <> ""]]>
      </Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243"
      Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0"
      Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="WixUI_Bmp_Banner" />
    <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23"
           Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
      <Text>Please enter database configuration</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6"
            Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
      <Text>{\WixUI_Font_Title}Database Settings</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
  </Dialog>
```

Which I am using to get connection string information from the end user in a user friendly way. I then set this value in a web.config file at install time using...

```
<Component Id="cmp623DDF82F0F7645ADAAF0E7573713162" Guid="{8CFDC325-BC71-4A2F-AB22-68B0AE56C98B}">
                <File Id="fil5B0B918C0DAF7B2ECC5EB9C7CC0B9FFC" KeyPath="yes" Source="Publish\Web.config" />
              <util:XmlFile Id="ModifyConnectionString"
                  Action="setValue"
                  Permanent="yes"
                  ElementPath="//configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='RawConnection'[\]]"
                  Name="connectionString"
                  File="[#fil5B0B918C0DAF7B2ECC5EB9C7CC0B9FFC]"
                  Value="[CONNECTION_STRING]"
                  SelectionLanguage="XSLPattern"
                  Sequence="1"/>
            </Component>
```

My question is, how can I set the connection string value by making a composite from multiple properties set in the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [MSI Community extensions](http://code.dblock.org/msi-community-extensions-deploying-databases) for this as it provides you with a nice interface and will format the string for you.

However if you want to build it up manually you can just do the string building in the `Value` attribute:

```
<util:XmlFile Id="ModifyConnectionString"
              Action="setValue"
              Permanent="yes"
              ElementPath="//configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='RawConnection'[\]]"
              Name="connectionString"
              File="[#fil5B0B918C0DAF7B2ECC5EB9C7CC0B9FFC]"
              Value='Server=[CONNECTION_STRING_DS];Database=[CONNECTION_STRING_IC];User Id=[CONNECTION_STRING_UI];Password=[CONNECTION_STRING_PASS];'
              SelectionLanguage="XSLPattern"
              Sequence="1"/>
```

Alternatively if you need to set a single property to use in multiple places you can either use the CustomAction or the SetProperty elements (they both do the same thing):

```
<CustomAction Id='SetConnectionString'
              Property='CONNECTION_STRING'
              Before='ExecXmlFile'
              Value='Server=[CONNECTION_STRING_DS];Database=[CONNECTION_STRING_IC];User Id=[CONNECTION_STRING_UI];Password=[CONNECTION_STRING_PASS];' />

<SetProperty Id='CONNECTION_STRING'
             Before='ExecXmlFile'
             Value='Server=[CONNECTION_STRING_DS];Database=[CONNECTION_STRING_IC];User Id=[CONNECTION_STRING_UI];Password=[CONNECTION_STRING_PASS];' />
```

Comment: I did what you suggested for the value attribute and it works great. In the future I will look into using the community extensions. Thanks for the help.